# Change value every nth iteration python

Tags: python, loops

How can I change a value inside a loop every 10th iteration?

Say I have a list with 30 properties

```
myList = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"........,"Thirty" } #trimmed
listLength = len(myList) #30
listRange = range(0, listLength) # 0-30

for i in listRange
    
    x = ???
    ...
    
    ops.mesh.add(size=2, location=(x)) # change value of x by 10 every 10 value
```

I would like to change the value of x by a factor of 10 every 10th time.

**Desired outcome**

```
first 10 values x = 10
second 10 values x = 20
third 10 values x = 30
```

**

Comment: Couldn't you do something like `x = 10*(i // 10 + 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo is a nice way of doing that:

```py
if i % 10 == 0:
  x+=10
```

Edit: you should probably initialize x outside the loop.

Comment: I think you mean `if i % 10 == 0`. The code given will increment `x` 9 times out of 10...